# Parsing String and put this in array

Tags: java

Can I get a method to parse a string eg: {"apple","fruit"} and put the elements in a two D array.

Comment: Yes, you can. Yes, you can.  Yes, you can.

Comment: Umm ... how do you put the elements of a list into a 2D array?

Comment: What are you trying to parse here?
Are you just trying to get each character of the strings in your first array, into a 2-d array?

Comment: yes getting the first and second names to put in a 2-D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) might be useful to you.